# Ubuntu Freezes, REISUB won't save me

Tags: 20.04, gnome, freeze, crash

I've recently come across a pretty distressing crash in my Ubuntu installation.

1. The mouse and keyboard will suddenly become unresponsive.
2. I thought the screen also froze, but it happened while I was typing in the
   terminal and I comically saw it fill with hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh,meaning that the last
   button pressed kept going
3. I tried ALT + SYSREQ + F and REISUB, but
   neither of them worked (perhaps because my keyboard doesn't even
   work when this happens?).
4. Pressing the shutdown button once will
   still give me the shutdown screen, telling me that shutdown will
   happen in 60 seconds, and the counter does decrement by 10 every 10
   seconds.

Not sure what my exact problem is here. Most answers I found pertained to a simple restart, but I don't think this would work anyway, since this has happened to me at least four times in the last 15 minutes. Here's hoping it does nottttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt - just kidding. Please help. Thank you in advance.

PS: Some info, in case relevant.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic
- CPU: Intel i5-1035G1 (8) @ 3.600GHz
- GPU: Intel Device 8a56
- (Also I use GNOME)

Comment: I'd root around in the logs to see if I could find any errors that pertain to this.